# Difference in two arrays

Tags: php, arrays, diff

I would like to get array with difference of two arrays, but `array_diff()` doesn't work how I want.

I have something like this:

```
Array ( [0] => dog [1] => cat [2] => cow [3] => bird [4] => wolf )
Array ( [0] => dog [1] => cat [2] => cow )
```

And I want to get this:

```
Array ( [0] => bird [1] => wolf )
```

Any ideas?

Comment: Wrap the output array of `array_diff()` in `array_values()` to renumber the keys at 0.

Answer (score 4):

Try this code :

```
$array1 = array ( 'dog','cat','cow','bird','wolf' );
$array2 = array ( 'dog','cat','cow' );

$diff = array_values(array_diff($array1,$array2));

print_r($diff);
```

Comment: Unfortunately it's not working, I've tried this already.

I'm getting:

    Array ( [0] => dog [1] => cat [2] => cow [3] => bird [4] => wolf )

Comment: Interesting, it work's with your example, but it doesn't with work with my arrays. Maybe the keys are making the problem? :-k

Comment: Unfortunately no, print_r($diff) gives
   `code`Array ( [0] => jaja [1] => mleko [2] => voda [3] => krompir [4] => meso )`code`

Comment: I can't realy help you since I don't know the content of the array $stack, try to print the content of the 3 arrays and see the difference (check if there is no spaces or anything that could make things go wrong)

Answer (score 0):

```
array_values(array_diff($array1, $array2));
```

Comment: Unfortunately it's not working, I've tried this already.

I'm getting:

    Array ( [0] => dog [1] => cat [2] => cow [3] => bird [4] => wolf )

Answer (score 0):

Ask i read your example there are two questions aback to you:
 - array can be the same key the same value, so you want find only deference key and deference value?
 - array only the same key but you want find deference value only?

Answer (score 0):

*You can avoid inbuild function*

```
$a1 = array ('dog','cat','cow','bird','wolf' );
$a2 = array ('dog','cat','cow' );

foreach($a1 as $key=>$value){
    if(!in_array($value, $a2))
        $s3[] = $value;
}
```

if u need vice versa diff in both the input arrays, then add the foll:

```
foreach($a2 as $key=>$value){
    if(!in_array($value, $a1))
        $s3[] = $value;
}
```